# -bash: grunt: command not found (nothing on SOF has worked yet)

Tags: node.js, bash, gruntjs, grunt-cli

I have tried everything I've found online and on SOF to fix the following problem and am coming up empty.

I'm on Mac and I built an entire web app use `node.js` and `grunt`. Everything ran beautifully until one day, I started getting this error:

```
-bash: grunt: command not found
```

Obviously, I did something, but I don't know what it is. I have tried:

- reinstalling
- [this article](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/grunt-command-not-found/)
- when I type `test -e ~/.bash_profile && echo "Found" || echo "Not Found"`, it echoes `Found`.
- when I follow the rest of the article, and try to install this is what terminal reads:
  [grunt-cli successfully installed with a warning and location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dybC.png)
- My bash profile reads:

  `export NVM_DIR="/Users/jennminerva/.nvm"
  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  export PATH=/Users/jennminerva/.node_module.global/bin/grunt`

  which I assume is correct but I'm quite out of my depth there.

I've been through literally every SOF entry about it, and I'm pretty sure I've tried all the solutions offered, so I assume I missed something, and I'm about to lose my mind.

Comment: Does your ~/.nvm directory still exist? `ls -l /Users/jennminerva/.node_module.global/bin/grunt`

Comment: The return is `Jenns-Air:~ jennminerva$ ls -l /Users/jennminerva/.node_module.global/bin/grunt
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  staff  39 Sep 17 02:57 /Users/jennminerva/.node_module.global/bin/grunt -> ../lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt`